# How to process (stretch) only the signal of a mix of gaussian?

Tags: numpy, image-processing, scikit-learn

I have a mixture of 2 Gaussians which I use GMM to separate. Once I predict and know which data point belong to which gaussian (0-background, 1-signal), I want to process the signal part only. Processing can be something like histogram EQ or clipping, but only on the results that are 1 (signal). Please provide an example on how I might do that, given `img` is the original image and `pred` is the prediction from the GMM.

```
img = cv2.imread(path, -1)
img_flatten = img.flatten().reshape(img.flatten().shape[0],1)

gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
gmm.fit(img_flatten)
pred = gmm.predict(img_flatten)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the signal in your flat image by selecting all parts from it predicted as `1`:

```
signal = img_flatten[pred==1]
```

I am not familiar with the processing methods you want, but for clipping values exceeding e.g. 0.5 you can use:

```
signal[signal>0.5] = 0.5
```

Finally you can reconstruct the processed image:

```
img_flatten[pred==1] = signal
processed_img = img_flatten.reshape(img.shape)
```

**Edit:**
I just spotted cv2 provides a histogram equalization method, so instead of what I wrote above, you might just use this for processing you signal data:

```
signal = cv2.equalizeHist(signal)
```

Comment: could you please demonstrate more on how I may do a histogram equalization or clipping on the selected signal (as part of the image)?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are after, but I added a couple of lines. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I was looking for something like [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html), but thanks for the code.

Comment: How about now? I just found cv2 already provides that function

Comment: `signal = cv2.equalizeHist(signal)` does not work since signal is not the whole image. The main problem is that how can I get back the whole image after processing the signal part. The other way would be to process selected pixels without separating it from the image. If I have a function `stretch(..)` that I want to apply to the pixels that are signal only (1), how can I do that?